# Display pickerview for select Date in Watchkit

Tags: ios, datepicker, nsdate, datetimepicker, watchkit

I am developing an application with the Watchkit Framework in which I want the user to select a date of birth and go to next screen.

For that I want to use the Pickerview in my application. But Watchkit doesn't have any UI Element for Pickerview.

In apple iWatch videos they have shown date picker in iwatch.

Is there any way to show a Pickerview type in WatchKit.

Answer (score 1):

I built one in swift, but it's on two screens: one for date, one for time. I only uploaded the necessary files, so you'll have to integrate it into your own project, or copy and paste it into a new one.

https://github.com/eamonnalphin/AppleWatchDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, but *you can use a date label and add buttons for the user to pick the date*. Its a lot of manual work but you can only do what apple gives you.